# Internal Error returned by Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, bigdata

google big query returns below error:

> job_sBmfBO_XIkCRrZTcVS9MoEGbOAA. An
>   internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

It appears when you do a `GROUP BY` when the group key has some null records. It return this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` will indeed work with NULL values. Try this query to see it in action:

```
SELECT MAX(x) AS max_x, y FROM 
  (SELECT 1 AS x, 2 AS y),
  (SELECT 2 AS x, 2 AS y),
  (SELECT 3 as x, 4 AS y),
  (SELECT 4 AS x, NULL AS y)
GROUP BY y
```

The problem you've encountered is actually a bad error message we'll fix with our next minor release. This particular error should be mapped to `RESOURCES_EXCEEDED`. Your query produced a very large single row, probably from GROUPing rows with many  key values that map to NULL, and then GROUP_CONCATing those many rows into a very large row. While some cases may work with larger individual rows, don't expect good behavior when producing rows larger than the import size limits at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#import.